# Tabela HTML em SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Será possível criar uma tabela HTML, dentro da tag `<svg>`? Tenho um exemplo, mas não consigo ver os objetos.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/XmC2A/18/

---

Answer (score 2):

tenta incluir o código na tag `foreinObject`

```
<foreignobject x="10" y="10" width="800" height="500" >
  <table border=1><tr> 
    <td> Olá mundo </td>    
    <td> <svg width="400" height="450">
            <rect id="rect1" width="300px" height="400px" fill="blue" />
        </svg> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</foreignobject>
```

Comment: Sim é o que tenho no meu exemplo. Aparece a tabela, mas não os objetos svg dentro da mesma.

Comment: `svg + html + svg` não estáva claramente dito no enunciado... (editei com base no teu exemplo remoto -- vê se faz sentido)